# What types of attacks are possible against this password generation scheme?

Tags: c#, .net, security, random, passwords

The code that follows uses the PRNG (pseudo random number generator) `Random` class to generate password characters for the initial temporary password instead of the much more cryptographically secure `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` as it should have used.

However, it does use the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` to generate a seed for the PRNG, so I'm thinking that's maybe worth *something*, instead of seeding based on the current time of day as is typical practice when using a PRNG where security is not a concern.

**My question is:** how easy or difficult is this approach to attack in order to compromise the password generation system and guess new users' passwords?

```
// Generate 4 random bytes.
byte[] randomBytes = new byte[4];
RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
rng.GetBytes(randomBytes);

// Convert 4 bytes into a 32-bit integer value.
int seed = (randomBytes[0] & 0x7f) << 24 | randomBytes[1] << 16 | randomBytes[2] << 8 | randomBytes[3];

// Now, this is real randomization.
Random random = new Random(seed);
```

The code then goes on to use `random.Next()` to generate characters to fill in the password string.

**DISCLAIMER**: This code is not of my invention. Do not blame me for it nor offer suggestions on how to fix it. I know how to fix it and I know it is bad. Do not waste time replying as such. Any comments or answers to this effect will be flagged as spam. I only found it in our code and am curious about its "security" properties.

Comment: Suggestion:  you might get more depths of security oriented expertise over at http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It seemed an appropriate fit for regular stackoverflow, but perhaps it might be a better fit for security. I did not know that existed.

Comment: Sure, and I wasn't saying it was inappropriate.  It's just that at SO, you'll get a bunch of people wanting to leap on the code per se, rather than eager to conceptually analyze the security.

Comment: You might want to take a look a the faq [How does the spam flag work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032/148672) Wasting the mods time to decline such flags probably isn't a good thing to do.

Comment: @ConradFrix: Who are you talking to? I didn't flag anything.

Comment: @JamesDunne My comment was on your disclaimer *Do not waste time replying as such. Any comments or answers to this effect will be flagged as spam.* I didn't mean to indicate that you had indeed acted on this.

Comment: To the closers: this is a perfectly valid question with a specific set of answers possible. It is not "not constructive". I don't know what makes you think that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue with PRNG functions is that of predictability.  Being able to predict it's output based on previous output.  The reason to avoid using the `Random` class is that by monitoring it's output, one can then start to predict future output.

The code above may or may not be a problem.  This boils down to how often the `Random` class is instantiated.  If you are creating a new instance with a seed from a crypto-strength PRNG and generating only a single password from that then you should be OK.  I say this because even if I learn the state of the PRNG from one generated password, it has no relationship to future passwords generated.

If you instead are using this routine to initialize a static instance of `Random`, then you certainly have a potential problem.  Let's say someone used this approach to send temporary reset passwords to an email.  An attacker could reset their own password enough times to start predicting the future passwords.  Once he can predict the next password, he simply initiate the rest for the account he wishes to compromise.  Already knowing the password that was emailed, he can then access the account.

Comment: Right, that's what I figured as well. It's much more difficult to attack since it's not instantiated with a seed based on the current time. The class is instantiated exactly as is shown in the class: on-demand when asked to generated a new password.

Comment: @James Dunne Incidentally, the downside to this approach is that you limit the amount of entropy to 32-bits.  So a brute force attempt is always 2^32 regardless of how long of a password is generated.  Usually safeguards prevent brute-force attacks online, but this would really bad for password protection on a local file.